# Node frameworks for command line apps?

Tags: node.js, command-line, architecture, frameworks

I'm trying to find a pretty simple framework that I use to organise the 'architecture' of a nodejs command line app.

I've found this site: http://nodeframework.com/ but it seems to be focused around web or network frameworks so am hoping someone could point me to something more suitable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out [Vorpal](http://vorpal.js.org/) and [Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js).

There are lots of interesting projects for building CLIs. I'll list some of them below:

- [Vorpal](http://vorpal.js.org/)
- [Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js)
- [Caporal](https://github.com/mattallty/Caporal.js)
- [Seeli ( C. L. I. )](https://github.com/esatterwhite/node-seeli)
- [Oclif](https://oclif.io/)

Comment: I maintain Gluegun, which supports TypeScript and plugins out of the box. https://github.com/infinitered/gluegun

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a new framework for command-line applications.

[Clirio | npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clirio)

This framework adheres to SOLID principles and is built using TypeScript. I designed it with inspiration from Angular and NestJS but in a simplified version.

Please take a look. I invested a lot of time and effort into this implementation

Additionally, I have created [a ready-made starter kit](https://github.com/stepanzabelin/clirio-starter-kit) for application development.

I invite everyone to join and contribute to the project :)